# Migrating wicket 1.4 to 1.5 - PageParameters.getAsEnum()

Tags: java, wicket, wicket-1.5

In wicket 1.4 PageParameters has methods like `getAsEnum(String key, Class<T> eClass`, `getAsInteger(String key, int defaultValue)`

In official migration guide theres this hint

> org.apache.wicket.PageParameters.getInt(String) - org.apache.wicket.request.mapper.parameter.PageParameters.get(String).toInt()

That explains how to get Int, Long etc if we were giving only String parameter but how do I refactor something like this?

```
params.getAsEnum("mode", PageMode.DISPLAY);
```

EDIT: I forget that you can call .toEnum() on StringValue. Sorry for mess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know of several ways how to do that:

```
// two interchangeable calls, first is more generic
getPageParameters().get("mode").to(PageMode.class);    
getPageParameters().get("mode").toEnum(PageMode.class);
// if you would like to have a PageMode.DISPLAY as default
getPageParameters().get("mode").toEnum(PageMode.DISPLAY);
```

Comment: yes thats what I wrote in "EDIT" section but since I havent answered my own question this is the accepted one :)

Comment: @ojciecmatki Sorry - I'm getting blind apparently. Thanks for accepting.